# Unable to click on a link which is visible to the webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
<ul class="first-of-type">

<li id="yui-gen0" class="yuimenubaritem service_management first-of-type yuimenubaritem-hassubmenu topmenu-selected" groupindex="0" index="0">

<a class="yuimenubaritemlabel yuimenubaritemlabel-hassubmenu" href="#Service Management"> Service Management</a>

<div id="Service Management" class="yui-module yui-overlay yuimenu yui-overlay-hidden" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">

</li>

<li id="yui-gen1" class="yuimenubaritem signal_management yuimenubaritem-hassubmenu" groupindex="0" index="1">

<li id="yui-gen2" class="yuimenubaritem change_management yuimenubaritem-hassubmenu" groupindex="0" index="2">

<li id="yui-gen3" class="yuimenubaritem substitution_management yuimenubaritem-hassubmenu" groupindex="0" index="3">

<li id="yui-gen4" class="yuimenubaritem video_configuration_standard yuimenubaritem-hassubmenu" groupindex="0" index="4">

<li id="yui-gen5" class="yuimenubaritem dashboard yuimenubaritem-hassubmenu" groupindex="0" index="5">

<li id="yui-gen6" class="yuimenubaritem administration yuimenubaritem-hassubmenu" groupind

I'm not able to click the link - <a class="yuimenubaritemlabel yuimenubaritemlabel-hassubmenu" href="#Service Management"> Service Management</a>
```

.

I tried using the below codes, but  it is not working.

Method 1:

```
WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Service Management"));
e1.click();

Method 2(used Explicit wait as well):
action.moveToEleement(e1).build().perform();
```

Please note that all the methods mentioned above is keep trying to click on that element for long, but never works for me.

Any suggesstion appriciated..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at tag, I can say there is a space before text `Service Management` hence use following(there is space before the text):

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText(" Service Management")).click();
```

or follow what Subhrajyoti Majumder has answered. Instead of my this answer, Subhrajyoti Majumder's answer is good. If it works for you, accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Either you go with the answer [TDHM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1471417/tdhm) provided, or you try going with XPath. That way I would probably click like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Service Management')]")).click();
```

The 'contains'-part will look for a text value of an 'a'-element that contains 'Service Management' (which our element does).

This way the script will work even if it is decided to remove the space before the text in the future.